# Hide BottomNavigationView in Navigation Component Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have implemented Navigation Component for multiple backstacks using Google's workaround using [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt). I want to hide the bottom navigation view when I navigate to a certain fragment(It is not a top level destination i.e I open blog then I go to viewing said blog in a different fragment).
This works using the following:

```
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
        val navGraphIds = listOf(
            R.navigation.blog,
            R.navigation.events,
            R.navigation.practice,
            R.navigation.login
        )


        val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
        val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
            navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
            fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
            containerId = R.id.fragment,
            intent = intent
        )

        //use this to setup Action bar

        controller.observe(this) { navController ->
            setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
            val id = navController.currentDestination?.id
            Log.d(TAG, R.id.blogFragment.toString())
            Log.d(TAG, id.toString())

        }

        currentNavController = controller
```

I want to hide the bottom navigation view when I navigate to this fragment. The problem is this is not a top level destination, so I **cannot** use NavController's addOnDestinationChangedListener() to hide bottom nav view. Would greatly appreciate it if someone helps with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use event  `navController addOnDestinationChangedListener` here a simple

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.fragmentA -> {
                    binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
                else -> {
                    binding.bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Like I mentioned , this will not work. Cause the NavController in the Main Activity only detects the top level destinations due to the fact there are multiple nav graphs and as such the NavController only detects the start point of each

Comment: @sinha-shaurya I'm using those workarounds as well and I'm doing the exact thing you do - bottom nav visibility based on the destination. Do it exactly like in NavigationAdvancedSample before 1.4.0-alpha01 navigation library update, or follow the update and try new sample version. They deleted those hacks from repo now. Anyway, it should work perfectly fine, just follow their steps exactly as they are.

Comment: Thanks, this was quite a welcome feature to be honest. Makes it so much better to use NavigationComponent now